# jboss testing url contains error in the url

Tags: jboss

I have installed JBOSS on my windows machine and I m wondering why on running the following URL : `http://localhost:9990/` it takes me to the following URL : `http://localhost:9990/error/index_win.html`. Just wondering why the URL has error followed by index_win.html ? I m pasting the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: I think the text on the page says it all

Comment: @FedericoSierra I didn't get you. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Maybe he means this part: "you have not added any users to be able to access the admin console". Just follow the instructions. There is no special "home page" for the server if you expected that...

Comment: @zagrimsan Is it mandatory to add users? I didn't add any.

Comment: I haven't used AS 7 so I can't say for sure, but to be able to use the admin console there certainly needs to be a user you can authenticate with. You have the instructions there, why don't you try it out? Or was this just a philosophical question about the "home page" URL and you don't bother about the admin console?

Comment: @zagrimsan It's not a philosophical question. Since I noticed `error` in the URL, I was wondering if I have done something wrong with the JBoss installation. Still not clear why "error" word is there in the URL

Comment: It is an error in the sense that you should be seeing something that can take you to the management console in the default page of the server, which you don't have there right now due to the lack of a configured management user. The server would likely redirect you to that same "error" page if you tried either of the console URLs mentioned in https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Management+Clients

Comment: I see. So there is nothing wrong with the installation.